# Extjs 5 model id' is not concatenating with REST URL - working in Extjs 4.2

Tags: extjs

Sorry!! may be i was not clear, I modified the question, Actual problem is that 'I am setting the id on the model and it is working fine in Extjs 4.2' and i am able to print the  id from within the model object on  console but ***this 'id' is not concatenating with REST URL like 'rest/update/user/123***'

I really need your help.
In Extjs 4.2, I am posting a form data to a rest url (update using proxy in model class ), it was working fine and send the request to the server as:

rest/update/user/123

but in Extjs 5 same request is being interpreted as:

rest/update/user //without he id of the object

it does not send the id of the object in the REST CALL URL (id has value inside the object)

//here is proxy in the model

```
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: ' rest/update/user'  
}
```

//controller

```
var model = Ext.create('MyApp.model.User');

model.set('id', "123");  // please see here, i am adding the Id so it is not phantom

model.set('userName', "john");
model.save();
```

Please help!!

Thanks.

Comment: You're creating the record without an id, which means it's a phantom.

Comment: thanks, i modified the question. please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model seems to be phantom (new). Call `model.commit()` before save.

Comment: I have tested it right now. Just do what I originally answered - add `model.commit()` before `model.save()` and it will work.

Comment: I have a another question!! I am able to submit the request fine, i printed my model and it has all the values on client side but on the server side only id field has a value and all the other field are null.'code' @PUT
    @Consumes({ "application/json" })
    @Produces({ "application/json" })
    @Path("/createOrUpdate/cvmSheet/{id}")
    ExtjsJsonSingleObject<PfCvmSheet> updateCvmSheet( @PathParam("id") final int id, final PfCvmSheet record);

Comment: Better would be to create it as a new question, I think.

Comment: thanks Saki!, i created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248792/extjs-5-0-model-post-values-not-received-on-server-side-working-extjs-4-2